# Java change tab ordering

Tags: java, jtabbedpane

I've setup a test of TabbedPane below. I want the tabs to order from top left to bottom right, which is the opposite of what is being produced by the code below.

Here is a picture of what is produced by the code below. This will be very difficult if I am trying to order the tabs by alphabetical order (just for example).

So just for clarity BBL13 should be BBL0 and BBL5 should be BBL19. Like this:

BBL0-BBL5

BBL6-BBL12

BBL13-BBL19

And not:

[image]

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    private Test() {

        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getCrossPlatformLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Main");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(600, 300);
            frame.add(createLayout());
            frame.setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    private JPanel createLayout() {
        JPanel mainLayout = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        JTabbedPane mainTabs = new JTabbedPane();
        mainTabs.setTabLayoutPolicy(JTabbedPane.WRAP_TAB_LAYOUT);
        ArrayList<JComponent> alBible = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            alBible.add(i, makeTextArea());
            mainTabs.addTab("BBL" + i, alBible.get(i));
        }

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        c.insets = new Insets(0,0,0,0);

        mainLayout.add(mainTabs, c);
        return mainLayout;
    }

    private JScrollPane makeTextArea() {
        JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
        textArea.setEditable(true);

        JScrollPane scrollTextArea = new JScrollPane(textArea);
        scrollTextArea.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        return scrollTextArea;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to reverse your loop. Something like `for(int i = 19; i >= 0; i--) `

Comment: reverse order throws BBL0 to rightmost.

Comment: Yes like yilmaz said. ;) This honestly doesn't make sense to me. If you start with a really long window of only one level of tabs and shrink the size of the window it drops the first set of tabs down rather then the end set! It's like the default setting is RTL rather than LTR.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the tabs at the top are controlled by `TabbedPaneUI`

```
public abstract class TabbedPaneUI extends ComponentUI {
    public abstract int tabForCoordinate(JTabbedPane pane, int x, int y);
    public abstract Rectangle getTabBounds(JTabbedPane pane, int index);
    public abstract int getTabRunCount(JTabbedPane pane);
}
```

Looking deeper into it, the default UI you're using is an instance of `MetalTabbedPaneUI`

This in turn has a `public class TabbedPaneLayout implements LayoutManager` containing `public void layoutContainer(Container parent)`

Putting together a test extending it

Answer (score -2):

It is impossible, at least to me. Because if the tabs were ordered as you want what if user selected BBL0 tab? How other tabs will be seen to user? Dream it.

Comment: Just because it's impossible to you does not mean it's impossible to everybody.  The question was posted for that reason, you and him do not know how, but somebody else may

Comment: Downvoted. Nothing impossible here. Start with leftmost tab as 0 and proceed to the end of the length and wrap to the next line over the top of the previous list and continue down the page row on top of row. In fact that make more UI sense to me. It looks like it's being built backwards.

Comment: @phflack so i said in my answer 'at least to me'. calm down and think twice.

Comment: @JohnSmith can you draw your explanation?

Comment: @yılmaz your post is not a good answer, you say it is impossible for yourself to do, so why not let somebody else solve/do it?  The rest of your post is more suited to a comment

Comment: @yilmaz - If you try running the code I included you will see. If you shrinking and expand the JFrame, the code for moving the tabs seems to be running right to left instead of left to right. IOW the tabs are being built from right bottom to left top. I've been messing with this and it seem that it might be the look and feel code, but I'm out of my league on that at the moment..